# How to organize End-to-end (.NET + Selenium) tests with multiple logins?

Tags: .net, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

I am writing some automated end-to-end tests in Visual Studio for a Web application, and scratching my head over how to organize them.  Different users will have access to different features of the app, so I anticipate a grid-like tool where we can check off tests (rows) that should run for each user (column).

How to handle authentication?  It seems needlessly slow to log in before each test and log out after, but where does the login step belong?  I THINK what I want is

```
For each user
    Log in
    For each test class
        If this test class applies for this user
             Run test methods
    Log out
```

I can't see a good way to organize this. NUnit's Factory seems to cut the other way (given a test, it could provide a set of users - but then I'd have to log in and out multiple times for every test).

Any suggestions about the best way to handle this testing scenario?

Answer (score 1):

We do handle same kind of scenarios using selenium `webdriver`. I hear your pain. Logging in with different authentication is painful. We did have multiple conversations how to reduce this painful repetition. But, unfortunately there is no way around. At least if you think about the purpose of selenium testing. Most people use selenium to replicate user behavior and acceptance testing. So, it is pretty much just doing what end user will do. But you do have a nice option of executing tests in parallel to reduce execution time. You can find some help[here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp). Selenium grid allows you to kick off multiple instances of tests to different slave machines. And, we organize our test using [Page Object Mode](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects). It also helps to reduce code duplication and maintainability.

**EDIT: NUnit test class demo**

```
using System;
using Netchex.Tests.UI.DataObjects;
using Netchex.Tests.UI.PageObjects.Test;
using Netchex.Tests.UI.PageObjects.Login;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace mynamespace
{
    [TestFixture(Browser.Chrome)]
    [TestFixture(Browser.Firefox)]
    [TestFixture(Browser.InternetExplorer)]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            //Run before all the test. Log in here and run all the tests for same user
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            //Run before each test
        }

        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            //Run after all test completed executing
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            //Run after each test
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestOne()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestTwo()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks, but I'm going to keep looking for some way to group tests for each user.... There must be a way to get at least part way there (say, run all the tests in a class under one login, then a second login, etc.)

Comment: I added a demo test class with `NUnit`. `JUnit` has similar concept and allows you to execute all the test for same user

Comment: Thanks for the example. Do you know a way to get NUNit / VS to run this test class multiple times, once for each user? I can't seem to use TestCaseSource (which needs a parameter to pass the user in) on the TestFixtureSetup method (which has to have no params).

Comment: It is possible. NUnit is powerful enough to handle multiple iterations. See [this](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5). I guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: Additionally, we do use an`enum` to handle our test for multiple browser which in your case is *user*. Simply you can handle this at `Class` level and iterate the tests multiple times. See my edit on demo class